# Loop through @ViewChildren native elements

Tags: angular

Given the following markup

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items">
    <input type="text" #val />
</div>
```

I defined in a component

```
@ViewChildren('val') rows;
```

And I disable the first input element with

```
this.rows.first.nativeElement.disabled = true;
```

How can I loop to disable **all** the inputs?

This doesn't work

```
this.rows.forEach(val => val.disabled = true);
```

and this doesn't work either

```
this.rows.forEach(val => val.nativeElement.disabled = true);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To loop through the children, use **toArray()** like so:

```
this.rows.toArray().forEach(val => val.nativeElement.disabled = true);
```